# How to incrementally merge small parquet files, using spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

We are having small parquet files arriving in HDFS every 2-3 mins from a spark streaming application. Files arrive in /table/landing/ dir

/table/landing/file1.parquet
/table/landing/file2.parquet
...
/table/landing/file9.parquet

We want to move these files to a /table/base/ table created using spark managed table where small files are partitioned on a partition key and merged with base data. This can be viewed as a "minor compaction"

We want to read files from /table/landing/ which are new i.e. arrived since past run.

Any idea, how this can be done using a spark batching application?

Comment: Incremental is a big term. Is the data based on ascending partition key?

Comment: Yes, we want to merge parquet files every 1-min or 5-min as they land in a HDFS dir and partition key is datetime_id (epoch long)

Comment: These are files as parquet? Why if they need to be merged?

Comment: these are small files in few MBs and we want to create bigger files (256/512 MB) to match the HDFS block size

Comment: Can be done but difficult in that you may get concurrent wrote errors. A lot of work for 15 pts

Comment: Schema changes? When can partition key data be no longer presented?